# MQL4 adjusted bid line

Tags: mql4

here goes a programming question only...

I'm trying to display an adjusted bid line with every tick.

In my EA I included the following code to create a horizontal line object and then move it every time around.

The problem is that the line doesn't show up to start.

Could you please help me to show the line on my chart?

```
if (!ObjectFind(0,"Hline"))
  {
     ObjectCreate(0,"HLine", OBJ_HLINE , 0 , 0, Bid + dBidAdjustLine * dPoint);
     ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
     ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_COLOR, Red);
     ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2);     

  }
  else
     ObjectMove(0,"HLine",0,0,Bid + dBidAdjustLine * dPoint);
  ChartRedraw();
```

Thanks!

Jean

Comment: Hi! What symbol do you use and what value has dPoint for this pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the object in `OnInit()` and then move in `OnTick()` only. Also `ObjectCreate` returns a `bool` so it is better to check if that function returns true, and then move to your level, not immediately

Comment: With all respect, there is zero need to create an object in OnInit()...

Comment: why should we check each tick if the object is found? if failed to move because object doesnt exist - it wil simply return an error. in order not to delete it manually - need to hide it when creating

Comment: If asking why to check per-tick, because this is a very common approach, as there is no other way in the MQL4 code-execution to re-new the such object, in cases it has been unfortunately deleted from the Graph. This principal construct is self-healing and can re-instantiate the needed object in any such case. Having spent several decades with augmented GUI / MMI interfaces, incl. MQL4 ones, I guess I know pretty well what self-healing code can do, once in production...

Comment: user 3666197, this code also works in OnTick() which solves the self healing question you raised: sorry, see below in an answer for code...

Answer (score 0):

### Let's check the nuts and bolts:

Run this right inside an **`OnTick(){ ... }`** handler code-segment and post a PrintScreen to show the product:

```
double   aLevel = Bid + dBidAdjustLine * dPoint;
Comment( "Level: ", aLevel, "LastError: ", GetLastError() );
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------    
if ( !ObjectFind(   0, "Hline" ) ) 
{     ObjectCreate( 0, "HLine", OBJ_HLINE,     0 , 0, aLevel );
      ObjectSet(       "HLine", OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID );
      ObjectSet(       "HLine", OBJPROP_COLOR, Red );
      ObjectSet(       "HLine", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2 );
      }
else
      ObjectMove(   0, "HLine", 0, 0, aLevel );
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ChartRedraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3666197, this code also works in `OnTick()` which solves the self healing question you raised:

```
if (!ObjectCreate( 0, "HLine", OBJ_HLINE, 0 , 0, Bid + dBidAdjustLine * dPoint));
      double   aLevel = Bid + dBidAdjustLine * dPoint;
      if (ObjectFind(0,"Hline" ) ) 
      {
         ObjectMove(0, "HLine", 0, 0, aLevel );
         ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID );
         ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_COLOR, Red );
         ObjectSet("HLine", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2 );
      }      
      ChartRedraw();
```